# jquery show and hide buggy with hover, better coding?

Tags: jquery

i know that it may be difficult to see the actual problem without looking throughout the whole script, but i'm curious if its a little buggy for anybody who has done a hover function and use show and hide.

My problem is that sometimes my element wouldn't show up, but when I move my mouse out and hover over again it shows. Its just not consistent of showing the element

```
$('.Item').hover(function(){
    var container = $(".show-element",this).attr("id");
    $('#'+container ).show();
},function(){
    var container = $(".show-element",this).attr("id");
    $('#'+container ).fadeOut(200);
});

<div class='Item'>
<div class='show-element' id='1'>Show</div>
<div id='1'>
some stuff
</div>

<div class='show-element' id='2'>Show</div>
<div id='2'>
some stuff
</div>
<!-- and so forth !-->
</div>
```

so this HTML shows a few div elements and my page has a while loop scripting through multiple elements.

Is there another way to do a hover a better way for consistency?

Comment: Look at this http://jsfiddle.net/fMbPr/6/

Comment: I suggest using `data-idt` instead of a `idt` attribute.  They can be accessed using `.attr('data-idt')` or `.data('idt')`.  You also shouldn't have IDs that start with a number.

Comment: @Rocket I agree i saw your demo and it is a better approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely just need to [stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) and end the animation. Hovering off multiple times before the 200ms has expired can produce undesired effects.

```
$('.Item').hover(function(){
    var container = $(".show-element",this).attr("id");
    $('#'+container ).stop(true, true).show();
},function(){
    var container = $(".show-element",this).attr("id");
    $('#'+container ).stop(true, true).fadeOut(200);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here, is that you have multiple elements with the same ID.  You can't do that (you also can't have IDs that start with a number).  You also have multiple `.show-element` divs inside `Item` (`.attr` only gets the info from the 1st one).

You should use classes, or unique IDs to find the elements you want to show/hide, and you should make your hover event more specific.  Like this:

HTML

```
<div class='Item'>
    <div class='show-element' id='show_1'>Show</div>
    <div id="info_1">some stuff</div>

    <div class='show-element' id='show_2'>Show</div>
    <div id="info_2">some stuff</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$('.show-element', '.Item').hover(function() {
    var container = $(this).attr("id").replace('show_', 'info_');
    $('#' + container).show();
}, function() {
    var container = $(this).attr("id").replace('show_', 'info_');
    $('#' + container).fadeOut(200);
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/CNy22/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that happens because you are generating invalid Html code, AFAIK (correct me) ids cannot start with a number, see [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same ID's more than once, which will definitely cause problems.

You can try something more like:

```
$('.Item').hover(function(){
    var container = $(".show-element",this).attr("alt");
    $('#'+container ).show();
},function(){
    var container = $(".show-element",this).attr("alt");
    $('#'+container ).fadeOut(200);
});
```

html:

```
<div class='Item'>
    <div class='show-element' alt='id1'>Show</div>
    <div id='id1'>
        some stuff
    </div>
```

Doesn't neccessarily have to be 'alt', it just shouldn't be ID if you are using the same one elsewhere. Also, it may work, but you should have a class or ID starting with a number.

Comment: Don't misuse attributes to store arbitrary data.  I suggest using `name`, or better use a `data-` attribute (`<div class='show-element' data-idnum='id1'>Show</div>`).  `data-` attributes can be accessed using `.attr('data-idnum')` or `.data('idnum')`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this any better? http://jsfiddle.net/BBtJ6/1/

Comment: you cannot use same id's more than once

Comment: Passing 2 functions to [`.hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) is *exactly the same* as binding to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.  It's shorthand.

Comment: Modified to account for "ids". Wasn't sure if hover's underlying methods were mouseover/mouseout or mouseenter/mouseleave thus the explicit declaration.